# How to completely delete/uninstall eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, uninstallation, android-sdk-manager

I tried downloading and installing eclipse because I want to explore android programming. I tried downloading and installing all the tools in the android device manager without thinking about how much space it can use. The downloads used 14 gb in my disk and I'm already regretting it. I tried deleting all my eclipse file but it still uses the same amount on my disk. Is there anything I can do to completely remove all eclipse files in my computer?

Comment: delete eclipse folder, delete **android SDK** folder, delete related folders which can be found in user's folder **c:\users\userName**, delete related folders which can be found in user's **Documents** folder (Use **shift+delete**) for permanent delete or **empty the recycle bin** after deletion

Answer (score 0):

normally eclipse works like a portable software. You can only install Plugins inside it, which will be saved in the plugin folder. So in my opinion you have to search manually where it is on your space and after this you better download right here: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

normally it must be done if you just delete the eclipse folder ...

Comment: I already deleted the eclipse folder :( But it still uses the same amount of space :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the android installation with all its packages : documentations, sdk, ecc... you can find them into the android folder,

`C:\Program Files\Android` in Windows

or open the Android SDK manager and remove every installed package.

Comment: The folder is empty and I already deleted all the folders associated with eclipse :(